# Probability of getting the product divisible by $3$.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

What is the probability that the product of two randomly chosen (distinct) numbers between $1$ and $100$ (inclusive) is divisible by $3$?

Now, what I am doing is to find out the number of ways of selecting a multiple of $3$ out of $100$ and then selecting any of the other remaining numbers. This can be done in $^{33}C_1 \times ^{99}C_1$ ways. The whole process of selecting two numbers can be carried out in $^{100}C_2$ ways. That gives the probability as: $ \dfrac { 33 } { 100 } $. However this answer is wrong. What's wrong in what I am doing?

The given solution considers two separate cases. First case, you select both the numbers as multiples of $3$ and in the other case, you select one multiple and one non-multiple of $3$. Why do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you tell how many times the pair (3,6) was considered in your solution?

Once, choosing a multiple of 3 like 3 and then one of the remaining numbers, 6.
Once again, choosing a multiple of 3 like 6 and then one of the remaining numbers, 3.

In you solution, the pair (3,6), just like all pairs with both numbers divisible by 3, was considered twice. That's why the solution split the problem in these cases.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Got it finally. :D

Answer (score 1):

You certainly need to consider more than one case. How you break it up is up to you.

If the first number you pick is divisible by 3 then you already have a success, probability 33/100.
If the first number isn't divisible by three (probability 67/100) then you draw the second number. The probability that this one is divisible by 3 isn't the same as it was for the first one because the first number is no longer available. This time it's 33/99 (=11/33), so the overall probability is (33/100)+(67/100)(11/33).

It sounds as if the solution you have gets to the same place a different way. If you take the probability that the first number is divisible by three OR the second number is divisible by three, you will have double counted the case where *both* numbers are divisible by three because that's considered in each case. To get the right answer you need to take one of them away.

Answer (score 1):

Non multiples of 3 in 1 to 100= 67.

Ways of choosing 2 numbers from these = 67c2.

Probability that it is a non multiple of 3 = 67c2/100c2.

Probability that it is a multiple of 3 = 1 - 67c2/100c2
                                                              = 83/150